# How to change all control's name attribute inside a DIV

Tags: jquery

i use the below jquery to change all name attribute value iterate by jquery. i try to assign id value to name attribute of all controls inside a div and div id is `Register`. here is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.each($('#Register').children(), function () {
                alert("pp");
                $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("id"));
            });
        });
```

when i am running my page then the above script suppose to run but it is not running. so guide me where i made the mistake. thanks

### UPDATE

at last this works

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Register').find('*').each(function () {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/ZyhPT/ are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: This seem to work fine on anton's fiddle

Comment: Yes.. It's working fine... It's assigning a values to name attributes... http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/ZyhPT/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [`.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) :-

```
$('#Register').children().attr("name", function (index, oldName) {
    return this.id || '';
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgVjv/)

Answer (score 1):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will only give you direct children (not all descendants).

You should use [`.find('*')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to have all the descending nodes.

Note : your code will add a `name` attribute to each and every descendant of your base node (include `div`, `span`, ...) . If you only want to update `input` nodes, you should add an adequate filter to `.find()` :

- [`.find('input')`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) will select all descendant nodes of type `input`
- [`.find(':input')`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) will select all descendant nodes of type `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`